# How to initialize foreach functions or variables to 0

Tags: php

Using the most current versions of PHP 7 I present the following error message:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

It seems that in PHP 7.1, a Warning will be emitted if a non-numeric value is encountered.

It says that to avoid these errors I have to initialize to 0.

They could explain to me how to do it, when the use of a forech is employed.

```
$meQty = 0;
foreach ($qty as $id_courses => $valueqty) {
    $meQty = $meQty + $valueqty;
}
```

Error line: `$meQty = $meQty + $valueqty;`

cart.php

```
<?php
    $items = (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
    $itemCount = count($items);

    $qty = (isset($_SESSION['qty']) && is_array($_SESSION['qty'])) ? $_SESSION['qty'] : array();
    $couponDiscount = (isset($_SESSION['couponCode']));

    $total = 0;
    $num = 1;
    $meQty = 0;
    $itemId = "";
    $meCount = $itemCount;

    foreach ($qty as $id_courses => $valueqty) {
        $meQty = $meQty + $valueqty;
    }

    foreach ($items as $id_courses => $item) {
        $itemId = $itemId . $item . ",";
    }

    $array = explode(',', $itemId);
    $strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1) . '?';
    $strTipos = str_repeat('i', count($array));

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_courses, courses, image, price FROM courses WHERE id_courses in ($strMarcas)");
    $stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$array);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id_courses, $courses, $image, $price);
```

The products are added to the shopping cart without problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QY2Z.png)

---

Using `var_dump($_SESSION['qty']);` show me

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195092/discussion-on-question-by-otto-how-to-initialize-foreach-functions-or-variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should assign  a proper value to the variable outside the foreach

```
  $meQty  =  0; 
  foreach ($qty as $id_courses => $valueqty) {
      $meQty = $meQty + $valueqty;
  }
```

you could also check for a valid numeric content

```
  foreach ($qty as $id_courses => $valueqty) {
      $meQty = ( is_numeric($valueqty) ?  ($meQty + $valueqty ) :  ($meQty +0);
  }
```

Comment: If I have this variable initialized with the value of 0, but the error keeps showing

Comment: I have edited my question and added all the operation of the cart

Comment: then  you have not a valid  number  in the $valueqty  .. you should check better the input  content  client side  ..

Comment: How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

As a more (IMO) suitable solution, if this is your only action within that loop, you can use `array_sum()`

> array_sum — Calculate the sum of values in an array

example:

```
$meQty = array_sum($yourArray);
```